# Parse negative currencies with parenthesis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following currencies in an import process:

```
$22.21

($55.95)
```

I can do `Money.parse('$22.21')` to parse into a [RubyMoney](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) object.

However, how can I parse `($55.95)` into a negative RubyMoney object? Do I need to parse it to a negative number first and then into RubyMoney object? It seems like a common request but I can't find anything via search for some odd reason.

If I get `-$55.95`, I can then run `Money.parse('-$55.95')` on it. Bonus points if the method can handle both positive and negative currencies.

Answer (score 2):

from the page that @swapnilabnave [linked to:](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency)

`:negative_format` - Sets the format for negative numbers (defaults to prepending an hyphen to the formatted number given by :format). Accepts the same fields than :format, except %n is here the absolute value of the number.

So you would use `(%u%n)` for the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regex to see if the string includes parenthesis.  If it does, remove them, and prepend a negative sign:

`str.include?(")") ? str.gsub(/\(|\)/, "").insert(0, "-") : str`

Examples:

```
2.0.0p247 :013 > str = "($55.95)"
 => "($55.95)" 

2.0.0p247 :014 > str.include?(")") ? str.gsub(/\(|\)/, "").insert(0, "-") : str
 => "-$55.95"
```

This works with positive values as well:

```
2.0.0p247 :016 > str = "$55.95"
 => "$55.95" 

2.0.0p247 :017 > str.include?(")") ? str.gsub(/\(|\)/, "").insert(0, "-") : str
 => "$55.95"
```

Comment: Depending on how well formed the data is, you could include the $ sign for a tiny bit more protection.

Comment: Or easier, if you are assuming the format is money: `str.gsub(/^(\(.*\))$/, '-\1')` or something like that. ;)

Comment: Good call @mbratch - my regex isn't that solid. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you can [delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-delete-21) the parenthesis and then parse

```
money = "($55.95)"
money = money.delete!('()') and "-#{money}" or money

Money.parse(money)
```

<s>It's in the readme of RubyMoney `sign_before_symbol`</s>

Why don't you use [number_to_currency](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) ?

Comment: You should make your answer more clear and helpful. You are referring to "`:negative_format` - Sets the format for negative numbers (defaults to prepending an hyphen to the formatted number given by :format). Accepts the same fields than :format, except %n is here the absolute value of the number."